# Remove-ADPrincipalGroupMembership 'insufficient rights'

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I have a Powershell script that removes a user from all AD Groups and it fails with 'insufficient rights' when I throw a collection of groups at it, but not when I remove a single group.

```
$adcred = Get-Credential
$adUser = Read-Host 'Enter username'
$adGroups = Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership -Identity $adUser | where {$_.name -ne 'Domain Users'}
Remove-ADPrincipalGroupMembership -Identity $adUser -MemberOf $adGroups -Credential $adcred

WARNING: Could not remove member(s) from ADGroup: '{-- snip --}'. Error is:
'Insufficient access rights to perform the operation'.
WARNING: Could not remove member(s) from ADGroup: '{-- snip --}'. Error is: 'Insufficient access rights to perform the operation'.
Remove-ADPrincipalGroupMembership : Could not remove member(s) to one or more ADGroup.
At line:1 char:1
+ Remove-ADPrincipalGroupMembership -Identity $adUser -MemberOf $adGrou ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (Microsoft.Activ...ement.ADGroup[]:ADGroup[]) [Remove-ADPrincipalGroupMembership], ADExcep
   tion
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : 1,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.RemoveADPrincipalGroupMembership
```

But it works if I manually enter one group name using the same credentials.

```
Remove-ADPrincipalGroupMembership -Identity $adUser -MemberOf 'somegroup' -Credential $adcred
```

My Powershell Windows is running under a non-Domain Admin account, but I provide the Domain Admin credentials in the script. Furthermore, if I run a new Powershell Window 'As different user' and provide my domain admin credentials, then Remove-ADPrincipalGroupMembership will work even when I throw a collection at it.

Comment: I need to refine my post with what I learned this morning. I can remove a single group or array of groups if I write it manually on the line like: Remove-ADPrincipalGroupMembership -Identity $adUser -MemberOf 'group1','group2' -Credential $adcred. But the Remove-ADPrincipalGroupMembership does not work at all with the $adGroups variable. So there must be something I'm doing wrong in the way I'm collecting the $adGroups variable.

Answer (score 0):

This should fix the issue. Instead of just giving it a string, you're giving the entire AD user object.

```
$adcred = Get-Credential
$adUser = Read-Host 'Enter username' | get-aduser
$adGroups = Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership -Identity $adUser | where {$_.name -ne 
'Domain Users'}
Remove-ADPrincipalGroupMembership -Identity $adUser -MemberOf $adGroups -Credential $adcred
```

I've tested thoroughly and it works. So does piping in the user

```
$adcred = Get-Credential
$adUser = Read-Host 'Enter username'
$adGroups = Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership -Identity $adUser | where {$_.name -ne 
'Domain Users'}
$aduser |  Get-Aduser | Remove-ADPrincipalGroupMembership -MemberOf $adGroups -Credential $adcred
```

Comment: Thank you for your improvement on the user portion of the script, but my problem is not with the user; it is with the groups. As I stated above, the console writes the error 'insufficient access rights to perform the operation' only when I supply a collection of groups--NOT when I supply a single group. While I incorporated your improvements, it did not fix the issue.

Comment: Perhaps it's a specific group? Have you confirmed you can do each of the groups in question individually? Your post just says "if I do one group."

Comment: It's not limited to a specific group. It appears to by any group in $adGroups, but not when those groups are listed manually like "-memberof 'group1','group2'

Comment: Try adding this to the beginning of the script

Set-ExecutionPolicy unrestricted -Scope CurrentUser -Force

Comment: Also, just for a sanity check run this and share the output  get-command Remove-ADPrincipalGroupMembership

Comment: For reference, my ExecutionPolicy was RemoteSigned, but I set it to your suggestion and this did not fix it.

Comment: get-command Remove-ADPrincipalGroupMembership

CommandType     Name                                               Version    Source
-----------     ----                                               -------    ------
Cmdlet          Remove-ADPrincipalGroupMembership                  1.0.1.0    ActiveDirectory